# do we have pypi counterpart in latex?

Tags: packages

In python, we can download package from https://pypi.org/ . Do we have some counterpart in latex?

Comment: Yes, ctan.org...

Comment: Nearly every package on CTAN is in the major TeX distributions (TeXLive; MikTeX). They have package managers, which you should (generally) use instead of downloading directly from CTAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the packages are at [CTAN](https://ctan.org/), and you would use the package manager of whatever distribution you installed.

For example, under Debian or Ubuntu, the system package manager includes numerous Debian packages, such as `texlive-fonts-extra`, which install bundles of CTAN packages, such as `newtx` and `ccfonts`.

Or, if you installed a Linux version of TeX Live (or more than one) under `/usr/local`, you would want to run `tlmgr` as the user and group who you installed it as (normally `bin` or something like `texlive`), for example, `sudo -u bin -g bin /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/tlmgr update --self --all`. You can put this in a setuid+setgid script in `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin` to give it a shorter name.

The Windows version of TeX Live has a graphical installer, which you can run as an Administrator from the Start menu, or you can run `tlmgr.exe` from an Administrator command prompt. You can also create a `.BAT` file or soft link with Administrator permissions to run `tlmgr update --self -all`.